# Using jQuery, how can I change the size of a div as I scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that is 500px wide in a container that is 3500px high, and I want the 500px div to slowly decrease in width to half its original width as I scroll down the page.  Everything I've tried with .scroll in jQuery is making the width change as soon as the page loads instead of as the page is scrolled down.

**EDIT** I'd like the width to scale up and down as the page is scrolled up and down.

Here's an example of what I started with, I know it's obviously not correct:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#box').scroll(function() {
    $('#box').css('width', '250px');
});
```

});

Comment: The way you've written your code, it'll resize on any scroll.  You'll want to add logic in the callback function to evaluate the position (likely with [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)), and then change the width accordingly . . . probably the `(3500-scrollTop())/3500*500` or something close . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working fiddle, that dynamically changes it's width http://jsfiddle.net/CWe9t/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var initialWidth = $("#box").width();
    var minWidth = 250;

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var x = initialWidth - (minWidth * ($(window).scrollTop()) / $("#box").height());
        $('#box').css('width', x);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling scroll function on your box scrolling? No, it's window you are calling scroll function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( **window** ).scroll(function() {
   $('#box').css('width', '250px');
 });
});
```

and about slowly decrease size apply this css3 properties on your box

```
 #box
 {
-webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }
```

apply css3 animation as it is more smoother to animate if many animations on same page same time and Jquery animation if that's only one simple animation as told by @daguru.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $( "#box" ).animate({
        width: '250px'
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```